# Why does the required attribute not work for me in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I set a `required` attribute to multiple input fields, which are created and sent like the code below. The problem is that I can send the form/field data when the fields are empty. What have I done wrong with setting the `required` attribute?

```js
function subone() {
  var fl = $("#Flaeche-Grundstueckthree").val();
  var zip = $("#Postleitzahl-der-Immobilie-2o").val();
  var and = $("#Anrede-5a").val();
  var name = $("#Name-5a").val();
  var maila = $("#maila").val();
  var tel = $("#Telefon-12a").val();

  var data = {
    fl: fl,
    zip: zip,
    and: and,
    name: name,
    maila: maila,
    tel: tel,
  };
  var ajaxurl = "send-data.php";
  // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    //var data = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(response);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input
      type="tel"
      class="form-field bg-image phone w-input"
      maxlength="256"
      name="Telefon"
      data-name="Telefon"
      placeholder="Telefonnummer für Rückfragen"
      id="Telefon-12a"
      tabindex="-1"
      required
    />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 30px">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 8px" required />
      </div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px">
        Durch das Anfordern der Immobilienbewertung stimme ich den
        Datenschutzbestimmungen zu. Ihre Daten sind bei uns geschützt und werden
        nicht an Dritte weitergegeben.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input
      type="button"
      onclick="subone();"
      value="Jetzt Bewertung erhalten"
      data-wait="Einen Moment..."
      class="button white-arrow vergleicher w-button"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-hidden="true"
      s
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your form in a `form` tag and change your `button` to `type="submit"`

Edit:
I moved the event handler from `onclick` for the `button` to `onsubmit` for the `form`.

Also, I add the below codes to prevent from submission if there is an invalid input.

```js
if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

```js
function subone(event) {
  if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }
  var fl = $("#Flaeche-Grundstueckthree").val();
  var zip = $("#Postleitzahl-der-Immobilie-2o").val();
  var and = $("#Anrede-5a").val();
  var name = $("#Name-5a").val();
  var maila = $("#maila").val();
  var tel = $("#Telefon-12a").val();

  var data = {
    fl: fl,
    zip: zip,
    and: and,
    name: name,
    maila: maila,
    tel: tel,
  };
  var ajaxurl = "send-data.php";
  // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    //var data = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(response);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="subone(event)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input
        type="tel"
        class="form-field bg-image phone w-input"
        maxlength="256"
        name="Telefon"
        data-name="Telefon"
        placeholder="Telefonnummer für Rückfragen"
        id="Telefon-12a"
        tabindex="-1"
        required
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 30px">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 8px" required />
        </div>
        <div style="font-size: 12px">
          Durch das Anfordern der Immobilienbewertung stimme ich den
          Datenschutzbestimmungen zu. Ihre Daten sind bei uns geschützt und
          werden nicht an Dritte weitergegeben.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input
        type="submit"
        value="Jetzt Bewertung erhalten"
        data-wait="Einen Moment..."
        class="button white-arrow vergleicher w-button"
        tabindex="-1"
        aria-hidden="true"
        s
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Changed everything you wrote. Now the validation works but the form is sent immediatly after clicking the button. After that the validation pops up. How can I make it send after every input field is filled with the right content?

Comment: @Vpor, I updated my answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Put your input elements and button inside `<form>...</from>` element, and make button type as `submit` instead of `button`.
On click of button, submit event is fired on the `<form>` element.

[Check docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event)

```js
function subone() {
  var fl = $("#Flaeche-Grundstueckthree").val();
  var zip = $("#Postleitzahl-der-Immobilie-2o").val();
  var and = $("#Anrede-5a").val();
  var name = $("#Name-5a").val();
  var maila = $("#maila").val();
  var tel = $("#Telefon-12a").val();
  console.log("submit form", tel);

  var data = {
    fl: fl,
    zip: zip,
    and: and,
    name: name,
    maila: maila,
    tel: tel,
  };
  var ajaxurl = "send-data.php";
  // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
  jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
    //var data = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(response);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="subone()">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input
      type="tel"
      class="form-field bg-image phone w-input"
      maxlength="256"
      name="Telefon"
      data-name="Telefon"
      placeholder="Telefonnummer für Rückfragen"
      id="Telefon-12a"
      tabindex="-1"
      required
    />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 30px">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 8px" required />
      </div>
      <div style="font-size: 12px">
        Durch das Anfordern der Immobilienbewertung stimme ich den
        Datenschutzbestimmungen zu. Ihre Daten sind bei uns geschützt und werden
        nicht an Dritte weitergegeben.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input
      type="submit"
      value="Jetzt Bewertung erhalten"
      data-wait="Einen Moment..."
      class="button white-arrow vergleicher w-button"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-hidden="true"
      s
    />
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Changed everything you wrote. Now the validation works but the form is sent immediatly after clicking the button. After that the validation pops up. How can I make it send after every input field is filled with the right content?

Answer (score 0):

Here **required** is an html prop and it will work only if you submit the form natively but you made it with javascript avoiding native html form checks. Instead of `onclick="subone();"` on your input use `onsubmit="return subone();"` on **form** element and don't forget to change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` on input.

Comment: Thank you it worked. But now I don't get a mail :( So there is an error with sending it?